# using element.AddClass to add an angular js directive, which is restricted to act as a 'class'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I made a directive in angular js restricted it to act as a class and this  directive makes my element drag-able.

On mousehover i want to do addClass and  add this directive which is supposedly a class, but this doesnt give the desired result, am i missing something? below is what I am doing

```
module.directive('myDraggable', function ($document) {

   var directiveObject= {

   restrict:'AC',

//logic of dragging
}
return directiveObject;
});
```

i try to do

```
 element.addClass('myDraggable'); // but this fails! pls help
```

Comment: Is the class not added or is it added but the directive doesn't work?

Comment: directive works fine all i want to do is make a few div s drag-able  depending on the return value of a web service thats why i want to add this directive to div on runtime.

Comment: Understood. But what I meant was: Does `addClass` not work or does the _directive_ not work although the class is added correctly?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I guess, Angular is not observing elements, if they get a new directive attached at runtime.
To make it work, you should recompile the element after adding the class with
[$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile).

Something like

```
element.addClass('myDraggable');
$compile(element)(scope);
```

regards

Comment: I tried to add $compile, but nothing happened there and even the element does not show up in the html. Do i need to add more?

Comment: I got 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) function. It's basically the same as a jquery element $(element)

Just do:

```
angular.element(element).addClass('myDraggable');
```